# How to center a circle on the right hand side of a rectangle with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a circle on each of the rectangles. Each circle should be centered from the top and bottom of the rectangle but ale placed on the right hand side.

Sample of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0,0) [trapezium,
                      name=trapezium,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=.1cm,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      trapezium angle=25] {};
      \node          [name=first,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of trapezium.south] {};
      \node          [name=second,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of first.south] {};
      \node          [name=third,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of second.south] {};
      \node          [name=fourth,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of third.south] {};
      \node at (2,0) [name=firstCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm] {};
      \node          [name=secondCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=1cm,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      below=of firstCircle.south] {};
      \node          [name=thirdCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=20pt,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      below=of secondCircle.south] {};
      \node          [name=forthCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=1cm,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      below=of thirdCircle.south] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Sample of output:

[image: output]

I tried to experiment with x and y axes but since I am looking to replicate this `tikzpicture` on multiple occasions on the paper I was looking for a more constructed solution.

Is there a better way to do it than what I do?

Comment: The desired placement of the circles is not clear. Also, why are the circles using `node` instead of a simple `circle`?

Comment: Most manual way and closest to your code would be to place the circle nodes `at (first.east)`, `at (second.east)` and so on. No need for `below=of` and `node distance`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - works great what you proposed and it makes sense. I do want though to be 0.5 cm left of the position. It currently appears on the line (west).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Yeah unfortunately since I added the `trapezium` I was not able to align them correctly. I am trying to place the circles on the east side and approximately 0.5 cm away from the column. I have not experiment with `tikz` for a very long time, hence my poor skills.

Comment: You might want to look into creating your own custom styles instead of having to use almost the same options for every node. You can add the circle to each node as a label. You could also make the whole construct be created out of nested labels to just one node, though you probably want to look into the concept of `pic`s which has much easier syntax.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - That is very interesting idea to use `label` and place a `circle`. I will give it a shot on the next attempt. Thanks a lot for sharing this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figured it out thanks to @Qrrbrbirlbel.

I also had to use `xshift=-5mm`.

Sample of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0,0) [trapezium,
                      name=trapezium,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=.1cm,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      trapezium angle=25] {};
      \node          [name=first,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of trapezium.south] {};
      \node          [name=second,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of first.south] {};
      \node          [name=third,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of second.south] {};
      \node          [name=fourth,
                      fill=blue!9!white,
                      draw=blue!50!white,
                      rounded corners,
                      line width=.05cm,
                      node distance=.05cm,
                      minimum width=5cm,
                      minimum height=1cm,
                      below=of third.south] {};
      \node at (first.east) [name=firstCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      xshift=-5mm] {};
      \node at (second.east) [name=secondCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=1cm,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      xshift=-5mm] {};
      \node at (third.east) [name=thirdCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=20pt,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      xshift=-5mm] {};
      \node at (fourth.east) [name=forthCircle,
                      circle,
                      fill=white,
                      node distance=1cm,
                      draw=blue!9!white,
                      minimum size=0.5cm,
                      xshift=-5mm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to replicate my shape? I am planing to create at least 5 more shapes like that.

Comment: You could use `anchor=east` and an `xshift=2.5mm` or an `outer sep=2.5mm` but these are all similar fiddley corrections which are dependent on the circle's size.